# How to get and set keys which are arrays in ES6 Maps?

Tags: javascript

I have an ES6 Map that looks like this:

```
let m = new Map([['a', 1], [['a', 'b'], 1]])
```

I can get string values like this:

```
m.get('a') // this value is 1
```

However, I can not get values which are arrays:

```
m.get(['a', 'b']) // this value is undefined
```

How can I get keys from a map which are arrays?

Comment: did u try `m.keys()` which returns an iterator?

Comment: thanks. i need to get the value not iterate over all keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b'];
let m = new Map([['a', 1], [arr , 1]]);
console.log(m.get(arr));
```

Maps use reference equality when retrieving values.